# Django - Pagination in DRF returns an error in VueJS

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework

Currently I'm using Vue in my JS file to consume my DRF APIs. Now when I add;

```
'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 100
```

In the console, an error is being returned; It says;

```
 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: status is null"
(found in <Root>)
TypeError: "status is null"
```

In **HTML**:

```
<select class="form-control" v-model="newJobRequest.status_of_the_job_request" required >
    <option v-for="status in statusOfTheJobRequests">[[status.type_of_status]]</option>
</select>
```

In **JS**:

```
getStatusOfJobRequest: function() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.$http.get(/api/v1/status-of-the-job-request/).then((response) => {
         this.statusOfTheJobRequests = response.data;
         this.loading = false;
     }).catch((err) => {
         this.loading = false; console.log(err);
     })
 }
```

Due to this error, I am blocked on my task to build a pagination in the table. I've also used DataTables in my use case, but due to this error I can't continue and reverted back to the original state. In the Browsable APIs the pagination doesn't have any problems. I've been searching for answers for the last 2 days and didn't find any similar problems regarding this, afaik.

Comment: Have you verified that `response` has a `data` attribute?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply, yes. This only occurs when I add the pagination in the DRF. And upon looking the in Vue devtools it returns the array(s) in the choices.   

Edited: In this application the Django handles the templating and the Vue js files handles the CRUD.